# How to wrap several printed values by defined symbol in __repr__()?

Tags: class, python-3.x, oop, printing

There is a new class. Each instance contain a refernce to next instance.
The goal is to build `__repr__(self)` function, that represent element of the class with all referenced elements, when each value wrapped by defined symbol. For example by `#` or `*`.
Something like this:

```
******  ******  ******
* 10 *  * 20 *  * 30 *
******  ******  ******
```

**There is an example:**

```
class Node:
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
            self.pointer = None

@pointer.setter
        def pointer(self, next_node):
            self.pointer = next_node


p1 = Node(10)
p2 = Node(20)
p3 = Node(30)

p1.pointer = p2
p2.pointer = p3

print (p1)
```

**That what I did:**

```
def __str__(self):
    ans = "{1} {0} {1}".format(self.value, "*")
    wrap = "{0:{1}^{2}}".format("", "*", len(ans))
    return "{1}\n* {0} *\n{1}".format(ans, wrap)
```

But it works only for one element.
For printing of all referenced elements i wrote another function:

```
def show(self):
        buf = self
        while buf.value:
            print(buf)
            if buf.pointer:
                buf = buf.pointer
            else:
                break
```

But it prints each element on a new line. Like this:

```
******
* 10 *
******
******
* 20 *
******
******
* 30 *
******
```

The problem is that i don't know how return on first line with some indent and print the next 3 lines elemen.

### The question:

Is there some way to build `__repr__()` function for representing all referenced elements?

Comment: Did you put `end = ' '` in ALL your print statements?

Comment: Where should I enter that code? I used build-in function `str(self):` for representing of each element. I made it by `.format` function. When i make printing, this function prints 3 lines simultaneously. How can i change **str** function into print command?

Answer (score 0):

That's I have done... **Forgive me for this huge code.** I am just pretty new in  python.

I solved it by `.format()` funtion. And by printing 3 lines at the output. **But i still wait and hope for more elegant solution...**
There is also option to change the wrapping character in `print_linked_list` fuction. And it prints only 5 following values.

```
def __repr__(self):
        return self.print_linked_list()
    __str__ = __repr__

    def print_linked_list(self, border="*", count=5):

        # examples of printing:
        # *****    ******    *******    ******    *****
        # * 3 * -> * 80 * -> * 100 * -> * 20 * -> * 8 *
        # *****    ******    *******    ******    *****
        ar = " -> "
        wrap, ans_string = str(), str()
        buf = self
        while buf and count >= 0:
            ans = "{0} {1} {0}".format(border, buf.value)
            ans_string += ans + (ar if buf.next else "")
            wrap += "{0:{1}<{2}}".format("", border, len(ans)) + \
                    "{:^{}}".format("", len(ar))
            buf = buf.next if buf.next else False
            count -= 1
        return "\n{0}\n{1}\n{0}".format(wrap, ans_string)
```